# IE11 Script1003: Expected "}"

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Works fine with Chrome and Firefox  but IE11 gives me the following Script error.

IE11 Script1003: Expected "}"
Please note I am executing a script from selenium. 
Ex: driver.execute_script("console.log(document.title)")
Can you tell me what if I have done any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly access the website using IE browser, and use F12 developer tools to check whether there have the same error?

Based on your code, I suppose you are using python with IE webdriver, I have created a sample using the following code, the code works well in IE 11 browser.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
driver = webdriver.Ie("D:\\Downloads\\webdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe",capabilities= cap)


driver.get("https://www.bing.com")

time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('sb_form_q').value = 'Hi webdriver'; console.log('hello webdriver');")

print("*******************")
```

Please try to test above code, if still not solve the problem, please post the enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).